# Stack Exchange Moderator Survey email - including non-moderators?

Tags: bug, moderation

Just wondering how many folks out there received this in their inboxes recently ... i'm a little perplexed since I'm *not actually a moderator* on any SE site.

Seems weird since the questions are implying an actual diamond-user (were you elected or appointed, etc.)

Did any other 20k+ non-mods get this survey, or am I just a glitch in the matrix?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/371881/855869

Comment: I didn't get anything like that.  I remember you ran for moderator a while back.  Maybe that's how you ended up on some dusty list.

Comment: I did get the "oops" email an hour or so after I posted this. And yes, I did try a few times and lost, so my "political aspirations" are null and void at this point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not the only one. See [this SO post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/371881/why-am-i-getting-the-moderator-engagement-survey). You should be getting an email soon saying something like

> **Please forgive us, we just goofed**
>
> I would like to sincerely apologize. I just mistakenly sent you an email that was meant for Stack Overflow moderators. Please ignore it.
>
> Thank you for your patience,
>
> Anita M. Taylor,  Email Marketing

To summarize - a survey is being sent out to all the mods and they made a mistake and sent it to a bunch of non-mods. The mods now have their survey and you guys get the apology email =) No need to fill anything out, obviously.

To quote Tim Post's answer there:

> This was a mistake on our end. In order to consolidate the places where we have people's contact information, we've been moving everything into one system. This has been great, we don't have to worry about spreadsheets and CSV files gathering dust in storage, but getting used to new stuff can get a little hectic.

Comment: Bingo. I got the oops email a little late.